# get value of inside a tag with jQuery.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can by jQuery get value inside tag `b`?

```
<span>
 <b>hi_1</b>
 <b>hi_2</b>
 <b>hi_3</b>
 <b>hi_4</b>
<span>
```

I want this output with jQuery: `hi_1, hi_2, hi_3, hi_4`

Please give me example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: -1 for not reading the documentation and trying something yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZDYnq/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var textArr = [];
   $('span b').each(function() {
     textArr.push($(this).text());
   });
    alert(textArr.join(', '));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the value inside a specific HTML tag in jQuery you can use the [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function.  This combined with a selector gets the output you're looking for

```
$('span b').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukNqp/)**

**[JSFiddle with commas](http://jsfiddle.net/ukNqp/5/)**

Comment: Is it possible to not use each? I.e. `$("span b").text().join(",")`

Comment: @mplunjan I don't believe that will work.  The `text` function will return it as a single `string` value so there is nothing to `join`

Comment: How about making it into an array first - like using $.makeArray or something... Also you do not get the commas in your example

Comment: Emma, change the console.log to alert if you want to see each element

Comment: @Emma in that scenario you're trying to `alert` on the result of `console.log`.  The `console.log` function has an undefined return value and hence you get the `undefined` error message.  You need to either `console.log` or `alert` the output.  Or do it as separate items as done here http://jsfiddle.net/ukNqp/3/

Comment: @mplugnjan missed the commas in her sample.  Will update.  Not sure about the `$.makeArray` solutions. Not familiar with that api

Answer (score 0):

This is cool

```
var x = $("span b").map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).toArray().join(", ");
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/M42Qx/)

[Discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7259162/295783)