# Alternative to jQuery each() - self educational question

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-selectors

Looking at this

[get value of inside a tag with jQuery.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258334/get-value-of-inside-a-tag-with-jquery)

```
<span>
 <b>hi_1</b>
 <b>hi_2</b>
 <b>hi_3</b>
 <b>hi_4</b>
<span>
```

where the question was to get a comma delimited string of the tag contents

the solution is a push inside an each.

Is there a shorter (and possibly faster) way using for example

`$("span b").text().join(",")` which of course does not work since text() does not return an array...

UPDATE:

the "bug report" (feature request) posted by artyom had this rather interesting snippet

```
var x = $("span b").map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).toArray().join(", ");
```

which is similar to BrokenGlass' solution but shorter...

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/M42Qx/

I prefer the toArray one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), but I doubt this would be faster since you have to convert from jQuery object to array and back to jQuery object:

```
var results = $("b").get()
                    .map(function(e) { return $(e).text();})
                    .join(",");
alert(results);
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/DNTdG/)

Comment: I like - I wonder which is better, yours or the one I found in the bug report

Answer (score 3):

This may be cheating, but since there isn't any text outside of the `<b>` tags, you can simply use `$('span').text()` to grab the inner text of the `<span>` and work with that instead...

```
$.trim($('span').text()) // Trim newlines near <span> and </span> tags
 .replace(/\s+/g, ', '); // Replace all other whitespace between <b></b> with ,
```

Comment: However it does not remove the newlines!

Comment: @mplungjan: Oops - I fixed it.

Comment: actually then you need (",") to not get too many spaces - http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/M42Qx/
Strange we cannot use \s

Comment: I think I got it actually sorted now.

Answer (score 1):

There was a [bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5858) about adding this functionality to the `text()` method, which was closed with *worksforme* resolution after a few ways to do this were provided.

Answer (score 0):

The only option that came to my mind, and far less impressive than [@BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259162/alternative-to-jquery-each-self-educational-question/7259279#7259279)'s alternative, is to use `filter()`:

```
var values = [];
$('b').filter(
    function(){
        return values.push($(this).text());
    });
alert(values);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/S9X7T/).

And this isn't that much different to a solution using `each()`, since it more or less does the same thing.